# Previously-Working Code Crashes Only in iOS5 as Static Library w/ EXC_BAD_ACCESS Code=1

Tags: objective-c, ios, background, location, static-libraries

So I have had a number of classes bundled together as a static framework using the universal framework project posted by Kyle here: https://github.com/kstenerud/iOS-Universal-Framework

Things compile and run just fine on iOS 5.0 up through 6.0, and have for several months now - I generally just copy the resulting framework into my project, link it up, and use it. It uses ARC for most classes.

Recently, I created a static library project from scratch in xcode 4.5 and copied all the classes from the framework into it. It compiled straight off, as did the project I added it to (previously used with the framework), but when I run it on my iPhone 4 w/ iOS 5.1.1, it crashes during runtime with an EXC_BAD_ACCESS message and doesn't highlight any specific code associated with the crash. Everything works well on the iOS 6.0 simulator, and an iPhone 4S I have that's running iOS 6.

The most I've figured out is that the error is occurring within a (rather large) block that registers as a background process and uses a location manager. I'm currently back-installing the 5.1 simulator to see if that crashes too.

Are there any major differences in the way static libraries and static frameworks are treated that I might not be aware of? Any significant differences between iOS 5 and 6 in that respect? I've played around with linker flags a little, including -ObjC and -all_load. Are there any pieces of code or error strings that would be helpful for me to post? I didn't include anything yet since i'm not entirely sure where the issue is...

Comment: have u checked by enabling zombie.. it may show u whr ur code is getting crash..

Comment: Recompiled everything for the simulator, tried to run NSZombie detection on it, and everything worked! No EXC_BAD_ACCESS errors at all. Still happens on the device, though.

Comment: check out if u have any non ARC classes.. go through release/autorelease objects

Comment: Vishy: The non-ARC classes (and all other code) has been in production use for ~6 months without issue, so I doubt it's that. I also just discovered that my static library actually WORKS on iOS 6 devices, just not iOS 5, even though it was written using all iOS 5 APIs...  Updated my question to reflect this new info.

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of static libraries!

Comment: So much pain in the ass...

I just figured out that it crashes in the 5.1 simulator and on 5.1 devices, but works on 6.0 devices and simulator. I'm going to start a new question thread because this one is no longer relevant. Thanks for the help, guys!

Comment: @Amos are you using xib, and auto layout feature..?

Comment: Nope, neither. Storyboard for basic hierarchy and programmatically-created views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some discussion on the apple dev boards, we discovered that I was compiling the static library using an iOS Deployment Target of iOS 6.0 in my project build settings. Switched that down to iOS 5.0 and voila, it works everywhere.

To be clear for future people who encounter this (using Xcode 4.5: Click on your root Xcode project in the file tree, then your Project name (as opposed to your Target), then then look under the "Info" tab for the pull-down that says "iOS Deployment Target" and switch it to the lowest OS version you want to support.

Comment: This helped me, thanks! You should mark this as the answer, even if it's your own ;)